# How to get scrolling to work on a touch screen for win forms app?

Tags: winforms, combobox, touch, scrollbar, touch-event

I have a Win Forms, C#, .net 4.5 application with a ComboBox.  The user has a Dell touch screen monitor.  When the user had Windows 7, they were able to touch the drop down box which would open it and the could touch anywhere within the drop down list to scroll up and down.  That is, they could touch any of the items (like on the white space) and drag they're finger up or down and the drop down box would scroll.  Since they've updated to Windows 10, this doesn't work.  They can click on the scroll bar and scroll, but it is hard to get your finger on it on a touchscreen.  They would like to be able to just bring down the drop down and start dragging the list up to scroll.  I've tested the app on other PCs with Windows 7 and Windows 10 and all have the same problem.  I've tried calibrating the touch screen in Windows.  I've looked for something I can add to the code, but haven't found anything.  Any ideas how to get this to work?

Here's the code to set up the touch screen:

```
this.BoxComboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
// 
// BoxComboBox
// 
this.BoxComboBox.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)    (((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.BoxComboBox.DropDownHeight = 750;
this.BoxComboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.BoxComboBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.BoxComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.BoxComboBox.IntegralHeight = false;
this.BoxComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 75);
this.BoxComboBox.Name = "BoxComboBox";
this.BoxComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1058, 45);
this.BoxComboBox.TabIndex = 1;
this.BoxComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new     System.EventHandler(this.BoxComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
this.BoxComboBox.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.BoxBarcodeTextBox_KeyDown);
```

Here's what the drop down looks like.  What they want to do is touch anywhere to scroll, like this:

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After quite long research, I found that enlarging the scrollbar width is the easiest way to tackle this issue. In Windows 7, there is an option in the Appearance and Personalization that allows to change Windows scrollbar width as shown in the image below:

[image: Change Scrollbar Width in Win 7]

This option is no longer available in Windows 10 or 11, you can actually use the tool that I published on my GitHub in the following link:

https://github.com/codewondo/Windows-Scrollbar-Width-Changer

This tool changes the scrollbar by modifying the registry.